# Using the clipboard in a function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I use the content of the clipboard in a function?

When I use `Paste[]` it copies it in the current cell of the active notebook. On the other hand, I can easily put an expression to the clipboard using `CopyToClipboard[expr]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using [ClipboardNotebook[]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502866/421225)

```
In[1]:= CopyToClipboard[expression]

In[2]:= an[ToExpression[NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]]]]

Out[2]= an[expression]
```

Although you should probably be more careful with it than I have been in the above code. See for example [Szabolcs' Mathematica tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867/421225).

Comment: Beat me to it by half a minute :-)  I believe you don't actually need `ToExpression` here, it might only cause an error.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It was close! In this case, I agree, you don't need the `ToExpression`. But in more general cases, I thought the box structures needed to be translated. Especially if the clipboard contents come from `CopyToClipboard[expr]`