# Unevaluated input of integer in Mathematica

Tags: input, wolfram-mathematica, integer

I'm having a very simple but nasty problem with mathematica:

I need/want to enter symbols using a leading zero

```
\[alpha]^0123
```

or even simpler just

```
mysymbol[0123]
```

which I then transform to my internal representation

(using the Notation package and IntegerDigits[] or Characters[])

```
==> myrep[{0,1,2,3}]
```

everything works fine for input without a leading 0.

BUT WHATEVER I TRY (Unevaluated[] or Hold[]), mathematica (it's overarching evaluator?) will transform the Integer

```
0123 => 123
```

so the 0 will be missing from my list

Of course, I could avoid the problem by requiring quotes or commas for the input, but that's rather unpretty!

ANY IDEAS?

Comment: NoEscape, the answer I gave you was wrong.  There *is* a way to do what you desire.  Please see my rewritten answer.

Comment: wow, thanks. 

my threat of downvoting seems to have worked pretty well ;o)

Comment: The carrot usually works better than the stick.  My original answer was *not* ignoring what you stated in the question, it was merely trying to explain what I (incorrectly) thought were the limitations of the system.  (Go ahead and delete the comments as they no longer make sense.)

Comment: It it just a matter of style.  I used the more restricted-domain function because that is the input I anticipated (and in fact filter for with `DigitCharacter ..`).  `FromDigits` is also faster than `ToExpression` in this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this question in a definitive tone, but I was wrong.  Expressions such as `0123`, `16^^8b` and `1*^6` are *not* converted during parsing as I had incorrectly recalled.  For this reason we would not need to fall back to the heavy duty and unwieldy [CellEvaluationFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5451304/618728) but can instead use the much more user-friendly [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PreRead.html).

This is still a little dangerous as once the definition to `$PreRead` is made it changes all input, even attempts to change `$PreRead`.  For example, if we were to set `$PreRead = Null &` it would become impossible to enter additional commands until the Kernel was restarted.

To enact your desired behavior as I understand it we may use:

```
mysymbol[s_String] := myrep[FromDigits /@ Characters@s]

$PreRead = # /. {RowBox[{"mysymbol", "[", digits_String, "]"}] | 
                 RowBox[{digits_String, "//", "mysymbol"}] |
                 RowBox[{"mysymbol", "@", digits_String}] /; 
                 StringMatchQ[digits, DigitCharacter ..] :> 
                 ToBoxes[ mysymbol@digits ]} &;
```

Testing:

```
mysymbol[0123]
```

> ```
> myrep[{0, 1, 2, 3}]
> ```

Comment: which is the best practice for setting $PreRead if I'm building a package - maybe it has aready been set by another package?

Comment: the FromDigits /@ in your first line works, but is misleading. It looks like we were trying to make an int again from the digits, which we are NOT. Why not use ToExpression /@ Characters@s

Comment: @NoEscape As I said, "`$PreRead` is still a little dangerous" -- You are quite right that it may already be in use, and that causes problems if you are trying to include something like this in a package.  I suggest you save the existing value of `$PreRead` (if defined) to another global variable, e.g. `$oldPreRead`, and apply it afterward.  Example:  `$oldPreRead = If[ValueQ@$PreRead, $PreRead, Identity];
$PreRead = ((# /. { (* replacements *) }) // $oldPreRead) &;`