# Is there a general way to do symbolic integrations in real domains, just like the way maple do[Assumptions don't work]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

`Integrate[m^2/((x - m^2)^2 + y^2), m]`

mathematica gives me a complex-valued reuslt, but maple 17 gives me what I want, see the attached picture.[image: maple v17 result]

I tried using assumptions, but it doesn't work.

In MMA, is there **a general way** to do integrations in real domains, just like maple.

Can this wrap bulit-in command proposed by Todd Gayley (see: [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag)) do the trick?

```
Message[args___] := Block[{$inMsg = True, result},
"some code here";
result = Message[args];
"some code here";
result] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg]`
```

Perhaps the reason for the complex-valude result is the invovled power calculation during the integration, so maybe what I really need is a general way to do symbolic power calculation in real domains?

thanks :)